# Looking for a list of all possible errors from a given method

Tags: swift

```
let url = NSURL(string: "google.com")

do {

    let dadosURL = try NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions())

}
```

Is there a way to know all the possible erros from the initializer above? Is there any apple's documentation where it is registered in?